# Как удалить в строке текст после пробела?

Tags: c#

Есть строка к примеру

```
str =("Успейте получить неделю изучения английского");
```

Как мне удалить все после - `Успейте получить неделю` 
Нужно,чтобы было после пробела в любой сроке я задаю к примеру диапазон к примеру от 20 до 50 знаков и режется все до пробела,чтобы слово было оконченное.

Мне нужна грубо говоря брать несколько начальных слов из текста и выносить их в заголовок.

Большое спасибо!

Comment: Режется _до_ пробела? Ничего не понятно.

Comment: нет режется после пробела

Comment: Дайте пример входных данных/параметров и желаемого результата. ЗЫ: Ага, теперь понятнее.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Судя по всему, вам надо [`string.IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5xkyx09y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
if (s.Length < 20)
    // короткая строка, что делаем?

var firstSpaceAfterLimit = s.IndexOf(' ', 20);
if (firstSpaceAfterLimit == -1)
    // нет пробела, что делаем?

if (firstSpaceAfterLimit >= 50)
    // следующий пробел аж за 50-ым символом, что делаем?

var cutString = s.Substring(0, firstSpaceAfterLimit);
```

---

Если нужно последнее вхождение, можно попробовать так:

```
if (s.Length < 20)
    // короткая строка, что делаем?

var lastSpaceWithinLimit = s.LastIndexOf(' ', 50);
if (lastSpaceWithinLimit == -1)
    // первый пробел аж за 50-ым символом или вообще нет, что делаем?

if (lastSpaceWithinLimit <= 50)
    // последний пробел до 20 символа, что делаем?

var cutString = s.Substring(0, lastSpaceWithinLimit);
```

Comment: @shatoidil: Пожалуйста! Но всё же, посмотрите на случаи в комментариях.

Comment: Судорожно извиняюсь, только начал осваивать программирование у меня в foreach будет if (s.Length < 20), как мне сделать так,чтобы он игнорировал эту строку и начинал цикл снова? Я правильно понимаю это надо сделать break; ?

Comment: @shatoidil: `continue`. `break` выходит из всего цикла, полностью. То есть остальные строки с `break` будут не обработаны.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @shatoidil: Не за что!

Comment: Оставляешь минимальное число символов, а логично максимальное.

Comment: @Qwertiy: «Логично» должно быть прописано в вопросе.

Comment: @Qwertiy: ...но специально для вас дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Можно дедовским сплитом взять массив слов и добавлять по одному в результат

```
var requiredLength = 5;
var inputStr = "asdasdasd asdasd asd asd asd asd asd";
var result = new List<string> {};
var currentLength = 0;

foreach (string word in inputStr.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
{
    if (word.Length > requiredLength)
    { 
        result.Add(string.Format("{0}...", word.Substring(0, requiredLength - 3)));
        break;
    }
    currentLength += word.Length; //adding word length

    if (currentLength > requiredLength)
    {
        break;
    }

    currentLength++; //space

    result.Add(word);
}


var output = string.Join(" ", result);
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь вот этим NuGet пакетом
http://humanizr.net/

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex.Match(s, @"^.{1,50}(?=\b|$)|^((?!\s).){50}").Value
```

http://ideone.com/puwTNS

Если нужно именно по пробельным символам, замени `\b` на `\s`.